# python map like object which contains lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

I try create map like object which contains lambda functions:

```
class Map(object):
    a = lambda x: True
```

But python assumes `a` as `Map` class method and expects what it accept `self` argument which is `Map` instance.

Of course I can write

```
class Map(object):
    @staticmethod
    def a(x):
       return True
```

But it is too long.
Is it possible to make the first class?

Comment: Is "too long" really an issue worth worrying about?

Comment: Why do you want this to be a class, not just a module of functions?

Comment: Note that while we use the phrase as shorthand sometimes, there's not really a `lambda function`.  It's just a different syntax for creating certain limited kinds of perfectly normal functions, usually for convenience when a function only needs to exist as an argument to another function.  If you're immediately giving it a name, there's not much reason to use a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just apply the `@staticmethod` decorator manually to the `lambda`:

```
class Map(object):
    a = staticmethod(lambda x: True)
```

or simply give your `lambda` that required `self` argument:

```
class Map(object):
    a = lambda self, x: True
```

Comment: Thanks, but I keep in mind maybe there is way without using decorator.

Comment: @Eugene: In Python 3, if you *don't* create an instance of `Map()`, `Map.a('something')` will work without requiring a `self` argument. But why bother with a class then at all?

Comment: @Eugene: If you are creating an instance, these two choices are it, really. You could write your own [descriptor object](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) to wrap the `lambda`, but that'd be enormous overkill for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you are asking. The first piece of code correctly does what it is supposed to do -- it sets that function as attribute `a` of `Map`.

```
Map.a(42)
```

> But python assumes a as Map class method

Python doesn't "assume" it is a "class method". It is not a "class method". All variables set in the body of a `class` declaration become members of the class. What were you expecting?

"Class method" refers to things with the `@classmethod` decorator. This is different from things with the `@staticmethod` decorator, and also different from things without either. As is, it is neither a "class method" nor a "static method". You need to understand the differences among all three.

The `@staticmethod` decorator only affects when you try to call a method on an *instance* of `Map`. You did not say you were doing any such thing. When accessing an attribute of class directly and calling it, there is no difference.